# Can a sentence start with "just so I/he/she/you/they can"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-starts, coordinating-conjunctions

I did the standard Google search and I checked Merriam-Webster. I found questions about starting a sentence with conjunctions such as "and" or "but". No joy for "just so [pronoun] can [verb]." Looking for answers with citations if possible. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Just so you can be confusing, you'll start this sentence in the middle?

Comment: Just so you understand, there is nothing wrong with this sentence.

Comment: Why am I typing this comment now? Just so I can add another example to the list.